# Non intersect between dbset<T> and List<T> c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my program.cs class:

```
List<WebApi.Models.Transaction> transactionsCSV = new();
```

and in my dbContext class:

```
public DbSet<WebApi.Models.Transaction>? Transactions { get; set; }
```

The list is populated with rows from a CSV.  The idea is that all these will get added to the database.  However, it should ignore any rows already in the dbset (Transactions table).

So I need to I need to delete any rows in the transactionsCSV List which exist in the Transactions dbset and it should match it by two proprties transaction.description and transaction.date.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: The operation wouldn't make any sense. `DbSet<T>` is a single-entity repository, not a data collection. It's used to construct queries that return data from a database as objects.

Comment: What you try to do is *very* slow anyway - load the entire table in memory, calculate the intersection without benefit of keys or indexes, then try to save the changes. A better way would be to load only the keys and filter the CSV data that already exists, eg `var newTransactions=csvTransactions.Where(tx=>!existingIDs.Contains(tx.ID));`. Even that's too slow and almost never used in production systems.

Comment: The *fast* way is to not use EF or any ORM, but bulk import the data into a staging table using `BULK INSERT`, `bcp` or `SqlBulkCopy`, then insert only the new data into the target table using a `LEFT JOIN` on the primary keys to find new rows.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your idea of using a staging table and bulk insert is exactly how I had done it in php / mysql, however I'm migrating this code over to c# and though I would explore the possibility of using EF..  I'll take your advise and pursue this approach instead

Comment: That's how everyone does it because it's fast. ORMs like EF are used to Map Objects to Relational data. There are no objects in an ETL job, only rows, fields, transformations. There's little point in pulling all data to the client, finding differences, then sending the differences back. What if you had a 10K row table? 100K? 1M rows? 1M rows is very little data these days.